How to mount nfs share with docker
I want to mount nfs share in my docker compose, but the documentation is lacking and I cant figure out how to do it corectly.
This is my compose.yaml file:
services:
  duplicati:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/duplicati:latest
    container_name: duplicati
    environment:
      - PUID=0
      - PGID=0
      - TZ=Etc/UTC
      - CLI_ARGS= #optional
    volumes:
      - ./config:/config
      - lalinap:/backups
      - /:/source
    ports:
      - 8200:8200
    restart: unless-stopped
volumes:
  lalinap:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      o: "addr=192.168.103.45,nolock,soft,rw"
      device: ":/Backup/Krystof/"
networks: {}

But it always reports this error or some simmilar variation of it when I try to run i:
wafadmin@odin:~/duplicati$ docker compose up -d
[+] Running 0/1
 ⠹ Container duplicati  Starting                                                                                                                                       0.2s 
Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/duplicati_lalinap/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount :/Backup/Krystof/:/var/lib/docker/volumes/duplicati_lalinap/_data, data: addr=192.168.103.45,defaults: invalid argument

Do you know what am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

MAybe you could try with this: lalinap:
driver: local
driver_opts:
type: "nfs"
o: "addr=192.168.103.45,nolock,soft,nfsvers=4"
device: ":/Backup/Krystof/"

@Macro I already tried that and it didnt help.
